# What is the significance of the Dragon's 3 names?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, names

In the *Wheel of Time* series, we see that Lews Therin Telamon has 3 names, but the majority of the other characters and Forsaken in the book only have 2 names. Is it unique that he has 3? Is it of any significance?

Comment: Is Lews Therin Telamon really a forsaken? If so, that needs spoiler tags.

Comment: He isn't saying that Lews Therin is or isn't a forsaken. He asks about the three names and says most of the other characters and forsaken. That implies he could be in either category.

Comment: Haven't read the books, but in RL the number of names is generally meant to indicate a direct relation to the person's social standing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It's significant but not unique.

From the companion volume *The World of Robert Jordan's Wheel of Time* (emphasis mine):

> The people of [the Age of Legends] had long outgrown any interest in material wealth as a goal unto itself. Status and honour were all-important, and could only be gained through service to the community. All hoped to be allowed to serve according to their gifts and to be found worthy of that service. Several sources mention the fact that even names reflect a person’s status and honor. **Everyone was born with two names and could earn the third one only through accomplishment, apparently possible in many fields.**

There were several other people in the Age of Legends besides myself who are known to have had a third name, including eight of the thirteen Forsaken:

- [Barid Bel Medar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Demandred) (**Demandred**)
- [Duram Laddel Cham](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Be'lal) (**Be’lal**)
- [Elan Morin Tedronai](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Ishamael) (**Ishamael**)
- [**Ilyena** Moerelle Dalisar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Ilyena) (my wife)
- [Ishar Morrad Chuain](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Aginor) (**Aginor**)
- [Joar Addam Nessosin](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Asmodean) (**Asmodean**)
- [Kamarile Maradim Nindar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Graendal) (**Graendal**)
- [Latra Posae Decume](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Latra_Posae_Decume)
- [Nemene Damendar Boann](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Semirhage) (**Semirhage**)
- [Tel Janin Aellinsar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Sammael) (**Sammael**)

Answer (score 1):

I'm at work, so I can't quote directly from the books until I get home, but the third name was granted to individuals who made great accomplishments. I seem to remember one book saying that one of the Forsaken was jealous that he never got a third name.

Answer (score -1):

Is it unique? No. Looking in the WoT wiki shows that several of the forsaken have 3 names.

### Forsaken:

Ishamael: **Elan Morin Tedronai**

Rahvin: Ared Mosinel

Demandred: **Barid Bel Medar**

Sammael: **Tel Janin Aellinsar**

Aginor: **Ishar Morrad Chuain**

Balthamel: Eval Ramman

Asmodean: **Joar Addam Nessosin**

Be'lal: **Duram Laddel Cham**

Lanfear: Mierin Eronaile

Semirhage: **Nemene Damendar Boann**

Mesaana: Saine Tarasind

Graendal: **Kamarile Maradim Nindar**

Moghedien: Lilen Moiral

Is it significance? No. At least nothing suggests it. We even have at least one character with 4 names in their full name.